# Finding subsets within a dataframe and writing the result

Tags: r, dataframe, match

- I have a dataframe of **35243 rows * 29 Columns**.I am trying to find subsets within this dataframe using the approach below.
- Given a single record, I need to retrieve the records most similar to it.
- apply function visits each row in the Dataset and subset function finds records that are similiar to the row currently being visited by apply function.

  ```
    findFragment<-function(Dataset){        
    df1 <<- data.frame(Col9=character(),aid=character(),month=as.Date(character()),year=as.Date(character()),Outcome=character(),ser_no=character(),Similar=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    rowind<<-0    
    start.time <- Sys.time()
    apply(Dataset,1,function(slic){
        rowind<<-rowind+1
        fragment<-subset(Dataset, subset = ser_no %in% slic[1] & 
                                               Outcome %in% slic[2] & 
                                               year  %in% slic[3] &   
                                               month %in% slic[4] &
                                               code %in% slic[5] & 
                                               name %in% slic[6] & 
                                               !(aid %in% slic[7]) &
                                               ((as.numeric(Percentage)<=(as.numeric(slic[8])+0.01) &
                                               as.numeric(Percentage)>=as.numeric(slic[8])-0.01)
                                               )
                        ) 

         #Refiltering results   
         #If result includes more than 3 rows then refilter back on these rows and include only those rows that have percentage+-0.0001
         if(nrow(fragment)>3){  
              fragment<<-subset(fragment, subset = ((as.numeric(Percentage)<=(as.numeric(slic[8])+0.0001) &
                                               as.numeric(Percentage)>=as.numeric(slic[8])-0.0001)
                                               )) 
          }     

         #Writing data is extremely slow in below way(takes 30+ minutes).            
         #fragmentize$Similiar[rowind]<<-paste(as.character(unlist(fragment[7])),collapse=",")

         #Writing data this way takes total execution time to 9 minutes   
         # df1<<-rbind(df1,data.frame(Col9=slic[9],   
                                      # aid=slic[7], 
                                      # ser_no=slic[1],                                           
                                      # Outcome=slic[2], 
                                      # month=slic[4], 
                                      # year=slic[3],                                                     
                                      # Similar=paste(as.character(unlist(fragment[7])),collapse=",")),make.row.names = FALSE)        

    })
    # df1<<-merge(x = Dataset, y = df1, by = c("Col9","aid","ser_no","Outcome","month","year"), all = TRUE)
    cat("Completed in",Sys.time()-start.time)       

  }
      fragmentize$Similiar<-0
      findFragment(fragmentize)
  ```
- It is taking 4 minutes 40 seconds to just find the subset. Is there more effective approach to find subsets quickly and write results back in **least time possible**?
- Test dataframe I (Takes 4 minutes 10 second).

  ```
  fragmentize<-data.frame(ser_no=rep("A1",35243),Outcome=rep("A2",35243),year=rep("A3",35243),month=rep("A4",35243),code=rep("A5",35243),name=rep("A6",35243),aid=rep(letters[1:4],35243),Percentage=rep(1,35243),col9=rep("A9",35243),col10=rep("A10",35243),col11=rep("A11",35243),col12=rep("A12",35243),col13=rep("A13",35243),col4=rep("A14",35243),col15=rep("A15",35243),col16=rep("A16",35243),col7=rep("A17",35243),col8=rep("A18",35243),col19=rep("A19",35243),col20=rep("A20",35243),col21=rep("A21",35243),col22=rep("A22",35243),col23=rep("A23",35243),col24=rep("A24",35243),col25=rep("A25",35243),col26=rep("A26",35243),col27=rep("A27",35243),col28=rep("A28",35243),col29=rep("A29",35243))
  ```
- Test dataframe II : It Replicates pattern in my actual dataframe.Execution time is 21 minutes which is more as compared to 4 minutes 40 seconds for my actual dataframe.

  ```
  fragmentize<-data.frame(col9=rep("A9",35243),col10=rep("A10",35243),col11=rep("A11",35243),col12=rep("A12",35243),col13=rep("A13",35243),col4=rep("A14",35243),col15=rep("A15",35243),col16=rep("A16",35243),col7=rep("A17",35243),col8=rep("A18",35243),col19=rep("A19",35243),col20=rep("A20",35243),col21=rep("A21",35243),col22=rep("A22",35243),col23=rep("A23",35243),col24=rep("A24",35243),col25=rep("A25",35243),col26=rep("A26",35243),col27=rep("A27",35243),col28=rep("A28",35243),col29=rep("A29",35243))

  library(random)
  ser_noVal<-rep(1:831)
  OutcomeVal<-c("Aggressive","Balanced","Positive","Negative","Neutral","Conservative")
  yearVal<-c(2013:2017)
  monthVal<-c(1:12)
  codeVal <- c("A", "B", "C")
  nameVal<-randomStrings(n=33, len=2, digits=FALSE,loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)
  aidVal<-randomStrings(n=222, len=4, digits=TRUE,loweralpha=TRUE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)
  percentVal<-c(1:1561)
  fragmentize$ser_no[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(ser_noVal, c(6,70,4,83,1,92,1,1,6,16,8,3,376,63,735,23,28,3,24,1,84,13,119,7,5,4,1,29,1,27,7,3,9,7,4,11,7,14,2,1,1,16,5,150,31,10,1,1049,2,47,36,2,41,37,6,81,55,6,11,22,3,10,30,4,8,4,175,9,6,1,1,83,20,1,34,38,1,3,41,6,19,1,13,65,42,115,53,18,19,36,5,16,20,38,1,36,1,1,1,4,7,5,19,7,8,39,113,4,1,21,21,2,12,7,6,11,33,19,1,1,53,2,195,79,1,1,2,2,3,1,7,3,11,5,2,1,16,2,14,2,2,15,4,54,4,3,2,40,49,2,1,3,22,9,25,5,42,8,5,6,8,8,3,179,2,4,16,131,113,20,1,13,27,57,52,34,7,4,1,3,22,21,577,16,28,31,82,1,1,74,26,25,1,23,1,29,116,33,1,3,9,8,11,12,1,2,3,11,1,1,13,3,22,13,1,15,2,4,20,1,2,7,2,2,18,147,8,2,50,5,25,2,12,1,98,6,6,37,55,20,9,6,3,8,4,2,2,9,2,32,6,183,10,141,755,34,1,13,3,1,83,1,10,1,566,27,1,38,1,45,7,44,43,11,18,259,36,64,6,19,31,33,355,70,14,26,41,619,139,1,2,45,76,2,49,5,19,51,30,16,32,12,10,1,4,2,80,25,45,84,50,346,125,60,61,321,6,14,17,13,37,7,4,61,79,207,68,111,49,75,425,92,50,329,4,22,2,7,88,1265,3,22,41,10,29,1,37,3,1,13,20,35,10,33,26,5,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,6,14,2,4,2,20,921,132,9,8,114,438,57,37,10,1778,21,10,44,1,4,3,10,48,1,100,123,6,15,234,3,15,3,14,13,46,39,2,72,3,97,97,10,13,2,38,3,4,17,49,143,5,76,61,11,17,16,40,1,1,1,1,1,9,6,1,2,20,28,30,4,30,14,9,80,1,32,7,20,4,26,2,66,4,2,1,2,12,2,8,2,12,56,9,1023,33,19,1,3,46,1,6,88,40,84,85,35,28,314,3,7,61,79,34,55,2,23,1,10,1,2,77,6,70,40,1,4,93,1,48,3,5,17,2,8,1,2,1,7,27,13,23,4,4,4,7,1,2,1,1,2,18,13,44,32,1,2,2,8,103,1,6,366,4,4,5,2,6,15,6,30,10,1,3,1,2,4,20,8,1,86,3,3,3,2,4,76,3,436,4,1,10,28,17,39,1,1,896,21,12,24,1,177,29,8,3,36,14,2,6,9,1,17,5,2,113,48,2,8,15,155,34,465,23,1,222,1,22,14,23,4,11,3,18,12,17,2,5,3,7,4,2,1,1,1,2,2,9,185,22,11,1,1,14,3,3,2,11,2,4,2,1,4,17,4,213,7,62,1,210,126,38,1,391,2,6,67,44,21,19,16,98,14,4,1,1,2,197,8,31,1,48,1,10,9,36,24,54,65,1,5,5,12,224,13,41,28,7,339,50,5,9,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,7,1,35,11,25,1,2,12,23,4,14,6,2,3,20,36,7,2,6,10,22,1,2,6,2,18,14,15,10,24,11,3,78,2,1,10,236,293,25,43,5,14,4,32,29,4,1,6,6,9,1,202,173,1,12,1,18,1,55,56,3,9,4,3,12,4,2,32,3,22,7,45,15,4,5,4,3,2,1,7,7,12,4,1,2,8,166,1,10,9,15,1,1,11,8,26,67,1,288,39,3,31,4,25,6,7,4,22,5,3,1,71,19,3,5,19,4,27,21,4,22,5,1,52,1,7,70,27,277,1,4,1,80,1,141,10,4,6,3,11,5,6,15,1,1,1,6,1,2))   
  fragmentize$Outcome[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(OutcomeVal, c(21775,3034,126,10,10277,21))        
  fragmentize$year[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(yearVal, c(11,2709,8476,11308,12739))        
  fragmentize$month[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(monthVal, c(2536, 2535, 2780, 2616, 2902, 3190, 3274, 3553, 3623, 3515, 2339, 2380))        
  fragmentize$code[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(codeVal, c(7610,24718,2915))     
  fragmentize$name[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(nameVal, c(218, 917, 1736, 555, 42, 76, 79, 267, 1988, 116, 194, 161, 12, 353, 261, 285, 382, 6050, 2053, 45, 1, 276, 4598, 7543, 337, 14, 1, 591, 1020, 657, 139, 3995, 281))       
  fragmentize$aid[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(aidVal, c(310, 82, 26, 6, 493, 175, 31, 4, 19, 160, 263, 248, 68, 20, 666, 303, 6, 125, 190, 8, 108, 93, 206, 11, 278, 2, 273, 3, 3, 4, 285, 1, 555, 44, 93, 21, 94, 5309, 46, 25, 7, 249, 67, 20, 3, 15, 15, 16, 5, 12, 5, 17, 67, 44, 332, 57, 358, 25, 204, 8, 612, 108, 47, 273, 16, 20, 516, 16, 344, 33, 153, 4, 43, 73, 14, 37, 88, 7, 26, 23, 116, 33, 28, 66, 24, 21, 18, 32, 96, 6, 16, 3, 176, 121, 109, 177, 8, 30, 156, 117, 24, 90, 199, 236, 24, 25, 34, 20, 50, 14, 19, 30, 8, 20, 3, 10, 55, 24, 26, 17, 17, 29, 147, 148, 6, 2031, 65, 1135, 632, 91, 544, 1073, 11, 617, 15, 18, 2, 226, 182, 89, 513, 23, 149, 6, 398, 148, 13, 129, 323, 26, 4, 4, 155, 63, 32, 64, 23, 2, 120, 1, 2, 1, 10, 25, 120, 993, 5, 335, 40, 539, 413, 116, 78, 15, 38, 2, 15, 34, 271, 3, 604, 375, 52, 47, 459, 457, 177, 28, 293, 49, 266, 96, 1836, 18, 127, 18, 246, 5, 8, 4, 11, 102, 24, 21, 63, 57, 25, 22, 2, 1, 1, 51, 74, 56, 154, 97, 21, 31, 4, 3, 1, 11))            
  fragmentize$Percentage[sample(1:nrow(fragmentize), nrow(fragmentize), FALSE)] <- rep(percentVal, c(116,84,64,108,25,36,104,6,17,21,129,70,32,34,18,234,37,14,102,4,5,24,57,19,130,7,22,81,123,9,1,6,4,7,103,22,30,2,17,18,44,176,3,12,71,7,20,52,11,10,7,81,7,6,5,3,45,15,9,116,10,78,5,39,36,7,34,7,44,5,14,58,7,23,386,13,46,1,79,12,18,4,15,6,1009,6,47,55,36,18,15,2,1,2,297,39,6,18,50,33,18,37,632,5,26,28,31,187,15,26,9,1,38,27,9,25,2,4,486,49,11,104,130,6,3,9,6,3,16,5,9,392,96,9,4,7,1,39,35,8,3,12,14,94,309,59,3,15,1,18,85,277,13,6,3,4,68,204,2,7,59,5,19,189,1,440,2,44,109,151,2,45,6,3,131,18,23,17,334,1,103,27,18,2,27,2,75,98,7,19,2,72,1,10,82,17,256,20,17,1,92,2,1,13,71,3,21,13,86,1,16,1,83,103,226,1,26,20,1,63,1,7,9,10,51,2,155,70,11,4,10,2,49,152,9,2,42,9,21,53,33,11,1,101,8,49,1,3,1,2,4,141,9,17,163,44,7,36,121,17,32,6,4,2,26,9,4,72,1,22,70,3,1,4,1,74,24,41,39,30,8,1,27,4,30,1,73,4,21,10,9,8,117,9,65,3,6,24,14,2,4,89,6,2,20,49,40,266,3,4,1,23,1,28,14,17,22,28,20,1,6,58,25,10,4,6,37,168,11,8,3,58,4,99,62,20,22,15,2,20,1,32,3,3,9,4,19,1,7,33,1,18,4,1,13,13,11,38,27,1,20,176,18,10,1,1,15,20,3,21,13,4,49,6,10,22,2,1,12,10,78,7,5,4,13,7,22,5,8,10,72,2,17,1,9,1,13,14,129,21,2,12,1,13,51,12,138,3,3,9,9,6,17,11,13,4,1,6,15,11,1,102,15,2,1,4,5,48,7,12,4,2,2,6,20,9,2,28,25,1,1,12,16,30,12,10,4,3,2,88,13,1,216,13,9,1,3,11,12,9,7,1,1,48,6,2,16,2,1,4,2,12,11,16,11,1,7,67,3,2,1,6,323,23,1,25,5,2,5,57,10,50,5,97,4,4,19,5,2,1,5,5,4,7,4,2,6,4,1,1,2,1,5,2,13,13,1,7,1,6,3,43,3,1,47,8,5,1,179,97,5,10,40,1,5,4,3,11,1,4,2,8,1,1,3,7,5,1,54,1,7,2,3,43,1,1,3,3,1,191,27,1,3,1,19,51,3,3,3,33,4,41,2,15,2,2,6,114,1,1,1,2,2,13,1,1,3,1,1,3,3,1,1,107,2,7,2,10,2,1,1,30,1,42,1,1,67,1,1,11,3,48,32,1,4,2,58,1,1,149,2,17,1,40,97,1,2,6,1,20,1,1,28,127,30,1,1,14,13,5,84,5,2,4,1,86,4,13,15,18,18,11,8,3,1,12,49,92,5,3,2,100,12,81,1,6,64,7,15,6,20,13,82,46,19,26,7,67,2,6,9,1,29,3,1,10,2,64,5,18,107,203,9,2,2,101,52,2,6,1,70,7,10,86,1,1,1,7,1,15,1,1,51,4,44,5,15,2,50,79,27,12,64,1,17,32,54,44,114,1,34,4,12,96,56,1,31,5,1,3,37,4,130,5,4,3,1,26,2,20,41,9,1,37,4,18,1,2,157,30,5,5,27,6,30,1,20,42,1,51,34,7,12,16,1,57,1,1,40,29,1,37,36,32,2,14,43,3,4,10,2,2,17,36,27,10,1,53,101,111,1,10,56,2,1,43,152,8,103,2,29,2,44,2,18,44,87,49,5,43,16,13,1,53,26,30,6,17,7,2,24,36,4,41,2,17,1,24,1,7,5,8,14,1,38,45,14,38,22,10,2,11,8,13,3,28,1,19,1,18,14,15,2,26,2,15,27,1,3,22,28,49,10,2,1,20,22,77,1,2,4,122,1,1,44,1,14,15,1,70,4,4,25,54,10,34,13,17,2,2,23,30,13,1,2,10,15,1,14,30,23,1,1,21,15,12,1,13,2,1,6,26,3,12,1,62,10,15,3,21,34,14,3,10,2,35,18,6,1,90,44,1,1,172,3,7,79,13,37,2,13,23,8,2,10,59,1,12,1,107,6,11,9,25,4,1,2,26,14,18,8,322,1,19,1,6,162,1,9,19,2,9,5,3,12,50,4,16,9,5,34,14,10,2,1,46,40,15,3,13,55,20,93,8,1,2,25,8,7,58,14,17,3,1,7,2,5,3,4,1,131,3,1,2,7,18,45,6,3,12,8,11,18,5,13,7,35,7,1,8,4,5,15,49,6,1,1,80,11,2,5,1,5,19,20,179,22,1,10,1,9,48,111,3,21,1,3,17,20,2,2,2,7,3,6,1,6,8,12,5,5,1,129,1,1,2,10,6,8,16,8,2,2,9,20,1,74,5,42,5,1,1,1,2,14,4,12,9,47,12,38,1,1,3,8,34,1,5,1,4,4,21,2,1,1,14,95,23,14,2,1,90,7,7,32,8,6,1,2,19,12,1,2,7,30,4,1,10,1,2,7,1,7,3,16,1,9,4,3,5,1,76,3,17,8,1,6,70,3,1,11,3,7,27,1,2,40,2,3,7,6,8,3,1,49,14,56,1,17,2,5,5,70,5,13,3,10,2,3,10,1,2,4,5,94,1,3,2,1,5,2,6,4,4,5,6,12,1,16,68,1,4,11,4,4,1,9,1,6,3,9,5,4,50,3,1,12,4,1,5,2,24,35,2,3,2,60,1,3,2,6,3,2,2,9,7,1,11,12,5,4,3,56,7,1,5,1,1,4,1,18,5,1,1,9,159,1,11,2,8,2,3,1,1,9,3,7,2,68,2,5,43,2,4,38,1,5,2,26,1,4,2,1,5,10,1,4,2,1,8,2,6,86,2,2,1,10,3,1,4,10,3,35,17,3,4,14,1,1,17,4,6,39,3,13,50,6,3,3,38,4,1,3,2,26,1,5,28,2,5,1,1,21,1,13,6,2,4,6,13,3,5,9,3,2,1,32,1,8,20,2,2,8,2,2,30,1,9,2,4,4,4,1,13,1,45,2,5,3,1,1,23,12,1,2,1,1,1,26,1,14,1,1,6,1,10,1,10,7,2,2,1,1,1,4,11,4,2,2,1,3,2,19,8,5,4,3,1,1,52,4,1,1,2,3,4,3,1,23,23,2,2,2,1,1,9,6,2,26,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,10,4,7,27,4,2,1,1,24,3,3,2,1,3,5,2,4,14,1,1,4,3,2,1,18,1,1,2,4,2,1,5,2,1,5,1,4,1,1,5,1,5,1,1,3,2,1,5,1,3,1,1,1,3,3,2,1,5,1,4,5,4,3,2,1,1,1,4,6,2,1,1,1,9,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,5,5,8,1,1,1,2,6,2,2,4,1,3,2,2,1,9,1,2,4,1,3,25))
  rm(ser_noVal,OutcomeVal,yearVal,monthVal,codeVal,nameVal,aidVal,percentVal)
  ```

Comment: `subset` uses nonstandard evaluation techniques. Try to create a logical index `inx <- with(fragmentize, ser_no %in% slic[1] & ... & as.numeric(Percentage)>=as.numeric(slic[8])-0.01)` and then `fragmentize[inx, ]`.

Comment: `inx_fragment<-which(with(Dataset, ser_no %in% slic[1] &  ...  & as.numeric(Percentage)>=as.numeric(slic[8])-0.01))))` takes more than 20 minutes AND
 
 `fragment<-Dataset[which(Dataset$ser_no %in% slic[1] & ... & as.numeric(Dataset$Percentage)>=as.numeric(slic[8])-0.01))),]` takes more than 20 minutes

Comment: @HFBrowning: A test dataset is provided in the last bullet point of the question.

Comment: I would add an index and do an inner join of the dataset on itself once filtered on 7 first columns (keeping only 8 first columns for this step), but your example data is pretty much just the same row repeated 300k time, doesn't really allow much creativity.

Comment: @AkkiI My sense is your code example doesn't work. I ran the code example on a Windows 64GB RAM, Xeon 8 Core machine and it failed with ` Error: cannot allocate vector of size 415 Kb`. Can you run and share results with your example dataset? You said you ran it and took 4 minutes for the subset. Yes, there are ways to improve perf. here my sense is a working example would really help. Take care.

Comment: Its running on my computer. Sometime R gives this error,Please restart R and try once again even if the error persists then try removing `rowind` variable

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper. Please check updated question for patterns in my actual dataframe.

Comment: Have you looked at the data.table package? Fast and efficient subsetting is its forte. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement? For each row, you need the indices for all other rows which have identical ser_no, Outcome, year, month, code, and name; non-identical aid; and Percentage within +- 0.01?

Comment: @akki Are you on a *nix like Linux and OSX or on Windows?

Comment: @russellpierce **System Configuration :** Windows 10 Pro 64 bit,16 Gb RAM,i5 2500 Processor

Comment: >For each row I need the content of ser_no for all other rows which have identical ser_no...
~~~
The result for this specification will always be identical to `fragmentize$ser_no`, no matter what the other requirements are. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @W.Murphy Sorry, For each row I need the value of aid for all other rows which have identical ser_no, Outcome, year, month, code, and name and not the indices. Updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I have understood the question, the OP wants to find similar records in his production data set which have identical values in `ser_no`, `Outcome`, `year`, `month`, `code`, and `name` and approximately equal values in `Percentage` (within a given tolerance). The OP has requested to append the `aid` values of any matching rows except the `aid` value of the actual row.

On possible approach is a *non-equi self-join* using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
eps <- 0.01
system.time(
  setDT(fragmentize, key = c("ser_no", "Outcome", "year", "month", "code", "name", "aid"))[
    , Percentage := as.numeric(Percentage)][
      , similar := fragmentize[
        .(ser_no = ser_no, Outcome = Outcome, year = year, month = month, 
          code = code, name = name, aid = aid, 
          lb = Percentage * (1 - eps), ub = Percentage * (1 + eps)),
        on = .(ser_no, Outcome, year, month, code, name, 
               Percentage >= lb, Percentage <= ub),
        by = .EACHI, toString(setdiff(unique(x.aid), i.aid))][, V1]]
)
```

On my system, OP's *Test dataframe II* took

> ```
>    User      System     Elapsed 
>    0.61        0.00        0.64
> ```

which is magnitudes faster than the 21 minutes the OP has reported for this sample data set.

As result, `fragmentize` has gained an additional column `similar`:

```
str(fragmentize)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    35243 obs. of  30 variables:
>  $ col9      : Factor w/ 1 level "A9": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col10     : Factor w/ 1 level "A10": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col11     : Factor w/ 1 level "A11": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col12     : Factor w/ 1 level "A12": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col13     : Factor w/ 1 level "A13": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col4      : Factor w/ 1 level "A14": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col15     : Factor w/ 1 level "A15": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col16     : Factor w/ 1 level "A16": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col7      : Factor w/ 1 level "A17": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col8      : Factor w/ 1 level "A18": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col19     : Factor w/ 1 level "A19": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col20     : Factor w/ 1 level "A20": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col21     : Factor w/ 1 level "A21": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col22     : Factor w/ 1 level "A22": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col23     : Factor w/ 1 level "A23": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col24     : Factor w/ 1 level "A24": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col25     : Factor w/ 1 level "A25": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col26     : Factor w/ 1 level "A26": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col27     : Factor w/ 1 level "A27": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col28     : Factor w/ 1 level "A28": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ col29     : Factor w/ 1 level "A29": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>  $ ser_no    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
>  $ Outcome   : chr  "Aggressive" "Aggressive" "Aggressive" "Aggressive" ...
>  $ year      : int  2015 2015 2016 2017 2015 2016 2014 2014 2015 2015 ...
>  $ month     : int  11 11 5 5 2 10 5 10 2 5 ...
>  $ code      : chr  "A" "B" "B" "B" ...
>  $ name      : chr  "wt" "Ds" "UF" "Of" ...
>  $ aid       : chr  "UuaR" "uwIL" "9WAx" "h5eH" ...
>  $ Percentage: num  255 1295 168 549 85 ...
>  $ similar   : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "ser_no" "Outcome" "year" "month" ...
> ```

As `similar` is empty for the vast majority of rows, we show only the non empty rows and also only the relevant columns. Setting the keys has already sorted `fragmentize` which makes it easier to verify the result:

```
fragmentize[similar != "", .(ser_no, Outcome, year, month, code, name, aid, 
                             Percentage, similar)]
```

> ```
>     ser_no    Outcome year month code name  aid Percentage    similar
>  1:     13 Aggressive 2016     3    B   gZ 21So        525       59PL
>  2:     13 Aggressive 2016     3    B   gZ 59PL        529       21So
>  3:     15 Aggressive 2017     1    B   nt C2i4       1311       uwIL
>  4:     15 Aggressive 2017     1    B   nt uwIL       1323       C2i4
>  5:     15 Aggressive 2017     6    B   Wj hMo4        308       mrDx
>  6:     15 Aggressive 2017     6    B   Wj mrDx        308       hMo4
>  7:     48 Aggressive 2016    11    B   gZ 4LVK       1216       FtSG
>  8:     48 Aggressive 2016    11    B   gZ FtSG       1205       4LVK
>  9:     48 Aggressive 2017     5    B   nt 59PL         85       f1Fh
> 10:     48 Aggressive 2017     5    B   nt f1Fh         85       59PL
> 11:     48 Aggressive 2017     7    B   Wj lVpw       1021       mz3h
> 12:     48 Aggressive 2017     7    B   Wj mz3h       1021       lVpw
> 13:    252 Aggressive 2016     6    B   gZ bkk6         75       spPd
> 14:    252 Aggressive 2016     6    B   gZ spPd         75       bkk6
> 15:    255 Aggressive 2015     9    B   Wj 59PL         29       dceG
> 16:    255 Aggressive 2015     9    B   Wj dceG         29       59PL
> 17:    265 Aggressive 2017     9    B   FB FodL        756       twvT
> 18:    265 Aggressive 2017     9    B   FB twvT        759       FodL
> 19:    276 Aggressive 2016    11    A   gZ 59PL        949       M6sO
> 20:    276 Aggressive 2016    11    A   gZ M6sO        944       59PL
> 21:    288 Aggressive 2017     6    B   gZ 21So        878       Y9gk
> 22:    288 Aggressive 2017     6    B   gZ Y9gk        882       21So
> 23:    340 Aggressive 2015     7    B   nt FtSG        763       kBpV
> 24:    340 Aggressive 2015     7    B   nt kBpV        767       FtSG
> 25:    340 Aggressive 2016     4    B   Ds 21So        731       bkk6
> 26:    340 Aggressive 2016     4    B   Ds bkk6        727       21So
> 27:    340 Aggressive 2017    10    B   nt B4fM        673       M6sO
> 28:    340 Aggressive 2017    10    B   nt M6sO        678       B4fM
> 29:    340    Neutral 2017     8    A   Oa 59PL        872       Vyl1
> 30:    340    Neutral 2017     8    A   Oa Vyl1        872       59PL
> 31:    340    Neutral 2017     9    B   FB 59PL        723       75iU
> 32:    340    Neutral 2017     9    B   FB 75iU        723       59PL
> 33:    370 Aggressive 2015     6    A   gZ 3Xre        132       DWZh
> 34:    370 Aggressive 2015     6    A   gZ DWZh        132       3Xre
> 35:    370 Aggressive 2016     5    B   gZ 1reu       1162       jSL1
> 36:    370 Aggressive 2016     5    B   gZ jSL1       1158       1reu
> 37:    370 Aggressive 2017     3    B   Wj 21So        872       spPd
> 38:    370 Aggressive 2017     3    B   Wj spPd        867       21So
> 39:    370 Aggressive 2017     4    B   FB 0Xza       1547       NXGE
> 40:    370 Aggressive 2017     4    B   FB NXGE       1535       0Xza
> 41:    379 Aggressive 2015     2    B   FB mJAy        133       zQZw
> 42:    379 Aggressive 2015     2    B   FB zQZw        133       mJAy
> 43:    379 Aggressive 2015     7    B   gZ FtSG        201       spPd
> 44:    379 Aggressive 2015     7    B   gZ spPd        201       FtSG
> 45:    379 Aggressive 2016     8    B   Wj 75iU         95       HzTb
> 46:    379 Aggressive 2016     8    B   Wj HzTb         95       75iU
> 47:    379 Aggressive 2016     9    B   gZ F9c3        244       LpB1
> 48:    379 Aggressive 2016     9    B   gZ LpB1        246       F9c3
> 49:    379 Aggressive 2016    12    B   nt 4DGD        507       zYVN
> 50:    379 Aggressive 2016    12    B   nt zYVN        504       4DGD
> 51:    379 Aggressive 2017     1    B   Wj LpB1         85       gzvo
> 52:    379 Aggressive 2017     1    B   Wj gzvo         85       LpB1
> 53:    379 Aggressive 2017     9    B   FB Xo8U         60       hSJN
> 54:    379 Aggressive 2017     9    B   FB hSJN         60       Xo8U
> 55:    379 Aggressive 2017     9    B   Wj 75iU         12       Puss
> 56:    379 Aggressive 2017     9    B   Wj Puss         12       75iU
> 57:    379 Aggressive 2017    11    B   Wj 1reu        817 N7dg, SCPN
> 58:    379 Aggressive 2017    11    B   Wj N7dg        809 SCPN, 1reu
> 59:    379 Aggressive 2017    11    B   Wj SCPN        809 N7dg, 1reu
> 60:    379 Aggressive 2017    12    B   gZ B4fM         17       hMo4
> 61:    379 Aggressive 2017    12    B   gZ hMo4         17       B4fM
> 62:    379    Neutral 2016     9    B   Wj L58K        103       hMo4
> 63:    379    Neutral 2016     9    B   Wj hMo4        103       L58K
> 64:    379    Neutral 2017     6    B   gZ 21So       1016       I46B
> 65:    379    Neutral 2017     6    B   gZ I46B       1012       21So
> 66:    379    Neutral 2017     9    B   Wj 21So       1244       LpB1
> 67:    379    Neutral 2017     9    B   Wj LpB1       1240       21So
> 68:    379    Neutral 2017    11    B   gZ 3Vpo        483       spPd
> 69:    379    Neutral 2017    11    B   gZ spPd        483       3Vpo
> 70:    393 Aggressive 2015     2    B   FB 8SzN        323       cKuN
> 71:    393 Aggressive 2015     2    B   FB cKuN        322       8SzN
> 72:    458 Aggressive 2015     1    B   FB 75iU        972       GWLn
> 73:    458 Aggressive 2015     1    B   FB GWLn        977       75iU
> 74:    458    Neutral 2017     1    B   Wj 21So        483       59PL
> 75:    458    Neutral 2017     1    B   Wj 59PL        483       21So
> 76:    458    Neutral 2017     6    B   iN hMo4        802       spPd
> 77:    458    Neutral 2017     6    B   iN spPd        807       hMo4
> 78:    526 Aggressive 2017     3    B   Wj 4DGD        992       59PL
> 79:    526 Aggressive 2017     3    B   Wj 59PL        991       4DGD
> 80:    552 Aggressive 2015     7    B   Wj 9oyt         95       OWxi
> 81:    552 Aggressive 2015     7    B   Wj OWxi         95       9oyt
> 82:    552 Aggressive 2017    10    B   Ds 59PL        890       9WAx
> 83:    552 Aggressive 2017    10    B   Ds 9WAx        894       59PL
> 84:    561 Aggressive 2015     1    B   gZ f1Fh        949       spPd
> 85:    561 Aggressive 2015     1    B   gZ spPd        952       f1Fh
> 86:    561 Aggressive 2016     4    B   Wj I46B        776       hpRD
> 87:    561 Aggressive 2016     4    B   Wj hpRD        771       I46B
> 88:    561 Aggressive 2016     8    B   gZ eKpA        809       rp75
> 89:    561 Aggressive 2016     8    B   gZ rp75        807       eKpA
> 90:    561 Aggressive 2016     9    B   Wj 4LVK        882 CF4V, M6sO
> 91:    561 Aggressive 2016     9    B   Wj CF4V        878 4LVK, M6sO
> 92:    561 Aggressive 2016     9    B   Wj M6sO        882 CF4V, 4LVK
> 93:    651 Aggressive 2017     2    B   Ds 59PL        179       SCPN
> 94:    651 Aggressive 2017     2    B   Ds SCPN        179       59PL
> 95:    735 Aggressive 2017     8    B   iN M6sO        760       tNgx
> 96:    735 Aggressive 2017     8    B   iN tNgx        758       M6sO
> 97:    817    Neutral 2016     6    B   gZ I46B        197       SCPN
> 98:    817    Neutral 2016     6    B   gZ SCPN        198       I46B
>     ser_no    Outcome year month code name  aid Percentage    similar
> ```

As can be seen from rows 1 and 2, the detected similarities are symmetric, i.e, row 1 points to `59PL` as similar while row 2 points to `21So`. There are also two cases where 3 similar rows have been identified.

#### Explanation

1. `setDT()` coerces `fragmentize` to a `data.table` object, thereby setting keys on some columns. This is not required for the join but sorts `fragmentize` which helps to verify the correctness of the result. In addition, it may speed up the join.
2. `Percentage` is coerced to type `double` to prevent type conversions during the join. In *Test dataframe II*, the OP has created `Percentage` as `integer` type while the lower and upper bounds used for the *range join* are of type `double`. Note that `Percentage` is updated *by reference* or *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object to save time and memory.
3. A new column `similar` is created using the result of the *aggregating non-equi self join*.
4. `fragmentize` is right joined with selected columns of itself. These are specified as a `list` using the abbreviation `.()`. In addition, `lb` and `ub` are created as lower and upper bound for the approximate match with `Percentage` using a relative tolerance of `eps`.
5. The `on` clause specifies the columns which should match exactly in the join as well as the *non-equi join* conditions. AFAIK, it is not possible to specify an *anti join* on a single column. Therefore, the condition `aid != aid` has to be treated in another way.
6. The `by = .EACHI` parameter requests to join and aggregate simultaneously for each group of rows which match the join conditions. This avoids the creation of a potentially large intermediate table which holds all multiple matches.
7. The result of the aggregation is given by `toString(setdiff(unique(x.aid), i.aid))`. In case of multiple matches, each `aid` value should only appear once. Then, `setdiff()` removes the `aid` value of the actual row from that result which implements OP's requirement `aid != aid`. Finally, the result is collapsed to a single string.
8. The `[, V1]` expression extracts just the column with aggregated values which eventually becomes the new column `similar`.

Comment: Gives rror in `eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'lb' not found Timing stopped at: 0.06 0 0.1` lb,ub,x.aid & i.aid not found.   Did you mean writing `similar := fragmentize[` instead of `similar := df[`?

Comment: You are right @Akki, it should read `fragmentize` instead of `df` (Last minute change while entering the answer). Fixed the code now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The answer meets my requirements then. It is executing in `13 seconds` on my computer on the `actual dataset `and `1.3 seconds` on `test dataframe II`. Is more optimization possible on actual dataset?. Can you provide solution to my updated question('Refiltering results') if possible?

Comment: lb and ub should be : `ub=Percentage+0.01  lb=percentage-0.01`

Comment: Concerning further speed-up, I have asked @Frank for additional ideas. So far, we only came to the conclusion to post a feature request with the `data.table` developers asking for an anti join on one column, e.g., `aid != aid`.

Comment: The definition of lower and upper bounds will depend on the value of `Percentage`.  In *Test dataframe II* the values were given as integer numbers which span two magnitudes, e.g., 29 or 1158. Therefore, I have deliberately chosen a relative tolerance instead of an absolute. Please, feel free to chose what is convenient for your production dataset.

Comment: Dear @Akki, sure but I will have to come back later to this as I am tasked with other urgent matters. In the meantime, can you please explain verbally what the code change is about? Thank you.

Comment: What is the reason for looking for an exact match of rounded values only if a subset has more than three rows? That appears to be rather convoluted and may degrade performance significantly. Why don't you use rounded values for all cases?

Comment: Updated my question. I just explained it in wrong way on this dataset, sorry for creating the confusion. I think it quite easy to interpret the meaning of code now. Thanks! @Uwe

Answer (score 1):

The first step in R optimization is to vectorize as many operations as possible. Here we vectorize all of the comparisons for the columns that should be identical, and only do row-wise operations for aid and Percentage. The latter could be vectorized by doing a self-join and filter instead of the `mapply`, but we're already below the target speed.

```
library(dplyr)
start.time <- Sys.time()
fragmentize <- fragmentize %>%
  # group by all the columns that should match
  group_by(ser_no, Outcome, year, month, code, name) %>%
  #row-wise within-group filter for different aid and close percentage
  mutate(similar = mapply(function (aid_i, Percentage_i) {
    aid[aid != aid_i & abs(Percentage_i - Percentage) <= 1]
  }, aid_i = aid, Percentage_i = Percentage, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(similar = sapply(similar, paste, collapse = ", ")) 
cat("Completed in", Sys.time() - start.time)  
> Completed in 1.856045
```

Less than 2 seconds using the 35K row example dataset from your question. The trick here is that the bare variable names anywhere within a `mutate` call on a grouped data frame will evaluate to a vector of the values just for that group, so the `mapply` call performs a row-wise search to comparing the values of each row to others for matching, but within the smaller search space of just the rows that have already been identified as matching on all the grouping variables.

I would recommend omitting the final `mutate` to keep `similar` as a list column rather than a collapsed string to make it easier to work with, but I've included that collapsing step as you did in your example code to keep the timings comparable. Also note your code had a filter on Percentage within +/-0.01, but the example data had only integers in `Percentage`, so I did +/-1 instead. You would want to replace the `<= 1` with `<= 0.01`.

Comment: Sorry, I `don't need indices`, looking for storing `value of aid at corresponding indices` in similar column.

Comment: @Akki I've updated the answer to store the values of aid rather than the indices

Comment: `Test dataframe II` executes in 2.5 seconds and `actual dataset` takes 4 minutes.